# Удаление дубликатов по условию

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица в БД:

```
declare @Results Table
(
    ID int, 
    TestResult5 int 
)

insert into @Results VALUES (1, 3),
                            (1, 5),
                            (2, 3),
                            (2, 2),
                            (2, 4)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо удалить записи из таблицы, оставив лучший результат ученика. Т.е. после SQL-запроса должно остаться:

> 1 - 5
>
> 2 - 4

Как должен выглядеть запрос для решения такой задачи?

Comment: как то так: `select id, max(колонка с оценкой) from table group by id`

Comment: @Bald не совсем то. Мне нужно удалить остальные. Дело в том, что помимо столбца с оценкой есть и другие.

Comment: Т.е. вам нужна не выборка, а некий delete ? думаю на это стоит акцентировать внимание в тексте вопроса. И кстати какую из записей оставлять, если у ученика две записи с максимальной оценкой ?

Comment: @Mike правильно заметили. При одинаковом столбце `оценка` далее идет следующий столбец `Первичный балл`. Ну а если то и то одинаково, то просто нужно не трогать. Таких будет не много и я смогу удалить их вручную.

Comment: @Bald пытался упростить запрос. Я также обычно делаю. В следующий раз учту.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
delete A
  from @Results A
 where exists(
              select 1 from @Results B
               where B.id=A.id
                 and B.TestResult5>A.TestResult5
             );
```